# Cross-platform mobile notifications from Qt/C++?

Tags: android, c++, qt, mobile, notifications

The closest thing I've seen in the docs is the [QSystemTrayIcon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSystemTrayIcon.html) class, which seems to only be supported on the desktop.

Is there any existing hack or third-party code to send a notification on iOS/Android/WinRT (or possibly support for what I'm looking for in the dev branch of Qt)?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any existing hack or third-party code to send a notification on iOS/Android/WP/WinRT (or possibly support for what I'm looking for in the dev branch of Qt)?

I personally doubt it.

The reason is that, at this point of time these ports are quite new and immature, especially the iOS and Windows Phone. Let us put WinRT to the rest after the semi-official announcement from Microsoft they would drop (merge?) it.

Even the Android port, which is probably the maturest of all, has an android specific way of doing this demonstrated in the example:

[QtAndroidExtras - Qt Notifier](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the case. I guess I'll just have to look into adding this feature to Qt myself when I get to the point that I need it.